# Usar Hooks com Arrays

Tags: array, react, react-hooks

Gostaria de atualizar o valor de um hook de arrays, por exemplo o código abaixo eu só consigo atualizar o ultimo valor, mas eu gostaria de atualizar uma posição especifica, como por exemplo o Test[6] e depois atualizar o Test[1], mas não sei como fazer =/.

```
export default function Exercicio() {
return(

const onPress = () => {
return(
    setTest([...Test, 5])
)}

const [Test, setTest] = useState([]);

<View>
<TouchableOpacity
         onPress={onPress}>
           <Text>pos0 = {Test[0]} pos1 = {Test[1]} pos2 = {Test[2]}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
</View>


)}
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Por favor, não cumprimente, não agradeça, não implore por ajuda e não escreva coisas com "help" nas publicações. O site é técnico, vamos manter o nível assim.

Comment: Se ver outras publicações contendo os mesmos ou semelhantes equívocos, sinta-se no direito de sugerir edições a comunidade pressionando o botão [edit] logo abaixo da publicação e fazer as modificações necessárias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o comando, basta utilizar

```
setTeste({ ...Teste,[2]:1 })
```

para inserir na posição 2 do array de hooks.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).